# Entity Framework with temporal database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, temporal-database

Considering moving from a current database (that stores only facts which are believed to be true at the current time) to the [temporal database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) (that can support for handling data involving time).

I communicate currently with the database with Entity Framework, but is it as easy to continue using Entity Framework with a temporal database as back-end? I haven't found much examples from the web where queries are run against such database.

Comment: Do you mean that you are going to use a special DBMS, or are you going to change your schema to follow the temporal database paradigm?

Comment: That is open question still. I'm flexible. I could go to PostgeSQL for example or I can change the schema of the current database as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you have not yet decided how you are going to implement the temporal aspect of your database. You could use an intrinsic way of the DBMS (eg triggers, logging, special mechanisms like [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) etc). But anyhow you would ensist on the **relational model**.

Therefore, the general answer would be that **Entity Framework should have no problem playing with any relational model** as long as there is a proper EF data provider for the specific DBMS.

However, regardless of your final decision on how you would implement the temporal aspect of the database, I would be really **suspicious regarding performance** and definetely build a **load testing** mechanism before making the transition.

Hope I helped!